# How to do multi GPU training with Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I want my model to run on multiple GPU-sharing parameters but with different batches of data.

Can I do something like that with `model.fit()`? Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Keras now has (as of v2.0.9) in-built support for device parallelism, across multiple GPUs, using `keras.utils.multi_gpu_model`.

Currently, only supports the Tensorflow back-end.

Good example here (docs): https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-run-a-keras-model-on-multiple-gpus
Also covered here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/25737

Answer (score 2):

try to use make_parallel function in:
https://github.com/kuza55/keras-extras/blob/master/utils/multi_gpu.py
(it will work only with the tensorflow backend).

Answer (score 0):

In [kera](/questions/tagged/kera) multi-gpu model training is very convenient than ever. Check the following document regarding this: [Multi-GPU and distributed training](https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/).

---

In essence, to do single-host, multi-device synchronous training with a [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) model, you would use the `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` API. Here's how it works:

- Instantiate a `MirroredStrategy`, optionally configuring which specific devices you want to use (by default the strategy will use all GPUs available).
- Use the strategy object to open a scope, and within this scope, create all the Keras objects you need that contain variables. Typically, that means **creating & compiling the model** inside the distribution scope.
- Train the model via `fit()` as usual.

Schematically, it looks like this:

```
# Create a MirroredStrategy.
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

# Open a strategy scope.
with strategy.scope():
  # Everything that creates variables should be under the strategy scope.
  # In general this is only model construction & `compile()`.
  model = Model(...)
  model.compile(...)

# Train the model on all available devices.
model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, ...)

# Test the model on all available devices.
model.evaluate(test_dataset)
```